# Fail to insert values into custom cascading list in JIRA via SOAP

Tags: java, soap, jira

I create a custom cascading list with these values

```
TestCatA

- CatA_1
- CatA_2

TestCatB

- CatB_1
- CatB_2
```

create custom remote fields and issue with

```
RemoteCustomFieldValue[] actionParams2 = new RemoteCustomFieldValue[]{
         new RemoteCustomFieldValue("customfield_10012", null, new String[]{"TestCatA"}),
         new RemoteCustomFieldValue("customfield_10012", "1", new String[]{"CatA_1"})};
issue.setCustomFieldValues(actionParams2);
```

but the second value always fails with

```
faultString: com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteValidationException: {customfield_10012=Value: 'CatA_1' is an invalid Option} : []
```

Any hints or working samples ?

Answer (score 0):

This changed from JIRA 4.3 to JIRA 4.4. It used to use the values as Strings but now uses IDs I think. Also in the Python JIRA CLI I had to use customfield_10012:1 as the name of the child option.

Comment: Almost pointless to continue with SOAP. since Atlassian is dropping it in favor of REST. I started looking at the REST API.